# Translation of "Pledge"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-request

I have to write a text in Korean. In this text I must have a "Pledge" section where I must promise that I take full responsibility for what is presented in this text, however I don't know how to correctly translate "Pledge" into Korean. Can you help me translate "Pledge" into Korean? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe “[서약](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%84%9C%EC%95%BD)문(誓約文)”: a writing that makes solemn promises.

Answer (score 0):

In Korean, “pledge” mean “서약” and “맹세”
Please read https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/enko/806f67cc1e42402f804eef70264d1e22